# ¿Como agrupar o crear un arreglo en datos de un archivo json?

Tags: python, array, json

quiero modificar un archivo json donde existen patrones que se repiten y estos los quiero poner dentro de un arreglo.

Cabe mencionar que estas repeticiones pueden ser variables, es decir en una privada puede haber 3 casas, en otra 5, etc...

Estoy hablando de un archivo con más de 1000 registros y hacerlo a mano es muy tardado además que pueden cometerse errores.

El contenido del json es:

```js
[{
  "Colonia": "REAL SANTA CLARA",
  "Privada": "PALMA",
  "Casa": "400",
  "Habitan":"4",
  "Mascotas":"SI",
  "Casa": "401",
  "Habitan":"1",
  "Mascotas":"SI",
  "Casa": "402",
  "Habitan":"2",
  "Mascotas":"NO"
},
{{
  "Colonia": "REAL SANTA CLARA",
  "Privada": "CIRUELOS",
  "Casa": "100",
  "Habitan":"2",
  "Mascotas":"SI",
  "Casa": "101",
  "Habitan":"2",
  "Mascotas":"NO",
  "Casa": "102",
  "Habitan":"2",
  "Mascotas":"NO"
}
}]
```

Y el resultado que quiero es el siguiente:

```js
[{
  "Colonia": "REAL SANTA CLARA",
  "Privada": "PALMA",
  "Casas":[
            {
              "Casa": "400",
              "Habitan":"4",
              "Mascotas":"SI"
            },
            {
              "Casa": "401",
              "Habitan":"1",
              "Mascotas":"SI"
             },
             {
              "Casa": "402",
              "Habitan":"2",
              "Mascotas":"NO"
            }
          ]
  },
  {
    "Colonia": "REAL SANTA CLARA",
    "Privada": "CIRUELOS",
    "Casas":[
              {
                "Casa": "100",
                "Habitan":"2",
                "Mascotas":"SI"
               },
               {
                "Casa": "101",
                "Habitan":"2",
                "Mascotas":"NO"
               },
               {
                "Casa": "102",
                "Habitan":"2",
                "Mascotas":"NO"
               }
             ]
  }
]
```

Me gustaría saber como hacerlo con Python. De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Puedes empezar definiendo las clases necesarias para la estructura de salida de ese JSON. 
``
def Estructura(object):
    def __init__(self, colonia, privada,casas):
       self.colonia = colonia
       self.privada = privada
       self.casas = casas

def Casa(object):
    def__init__(self, casa, habitan, mascotas):
       self.casa = casa
       self.habitan = habitan
       self.mascotas = mascotas
``

Comment: El problema es que el JSON contiene llaves duplicadas (casa, habitan, mascotas) y los diccionarios requieren llave única. Por tanto, cuando lees el JSON, el diccionario que recibes contiene solo una de cada llave repetida.
La única solución es transformar esos datos en un arreglo en el JSON original. Mira https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203165/dealing-with-json-with-duplicate-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una solución adaptada de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203165/dealing-with-json-with-duplicate-keys.

El método `json.load` tiene un parámetro opcional `object_pairs_hook`, que es una función opcional a la que se llamará con el resultado de cualquier literal de objeto decodificado con una lista ordenada de pares. El valor de retorno de object_pairs_hook se utilizará en lugar de dict.

En sencillo, json va a pasar a esa función todos los pares llave valor que vaya encontrando. Cuando esa función termine de procesar, devolverá un objeto. Ese será devuelto por `json.load()`.

La función recibe la lista de pares llave, valor en el orden en que van apareciendo en el archivo, devolviendo el diccionario generado.

```
import json, itertools

def duplicate_object_pairs_hook(pairs):
    def _key(pair):
        (k, v) = pair
        return k

    def gpairs():
        dic = {"Casas": []}
        for llave, valor in pairs:
            if llave == "Casa":
                #   Agregar un nuevo diccionario
                dic["Casas"].append({llave: valor})
            elif llave not in ["Colonia", "Privada"]:
                dic["Casas"][-1][llave] = valor
            else:
                dic[llave] = valor
        for llave, valor in dic.items():
            yield llave, valor

    return dict(gpairs())

with open("colonia.json", "r") as entrada:
    data = json.load(entrada, object_pairs_hook= duplicate_object_pairs_hook)
    for dic in data:
        print("----")
        for llave, valor in dic.items():
            print(llave, valor)
    with open("ordenados.json", "w") as salida:
        json.dump(data, salida)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Candid Moe, con unas adaptaciones que le hice a este código, ¡me funcionó perfecto!